# mysql unicode text incorrect string warning on insert, despite character set variables set utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

First, I know, yes, this is yet another mysql unicode question.

Problem: I am unable to insert unicode text into my mysql database

I want to execute the following query:

```
INSERT INTO usert SET username='田中'
```

When I do, I get this warning:

```
Incorrect string value: '\x93c\x92\x86' for column 'username' at row 1
```

A blank space is inserted into the table instead of the data

I have tried as many answers and forums as I could, and I believe that all appropriate variables, table, and column settings are set to 'utf8mb4' character set, with collation 'utf8mb4_general_ci' or 'utfmb4_unicode_ci'

I will tell you why I believe that by giving you the details, and sql commands used to show them.

First, mysql version:

```
mysql:> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'
```

Confirms that the version is `5.6.23`

To show the character set variables in mysql:

```
mysql:> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'
```

That command shows (in slightly different format):

```
character_set_client: utf8mb4
character_set_connection: utf8mb4
character_set_database: utf8mb4
...
character_set_results: utf8mb4
character_set_server: utf8mb4
character_set_system: utf8
```

Collation:

```
mysql:> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collat%'
```

RESULTS:

```
collation_connection: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_database: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

So far so good?

Now, for the table character set and collation:

Look at table details command:

```
mysql:> SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

shows that the collation is `utf8mb4_general_ci`

Command for looking at column details:

```
mysql:> SHOW FULL COLUMNS IN usert
```

Confirms that the collation for column 'username' is `utf8mb4_general_ci`

In summary, from what I have studied, all relevant variables, database, table, and column settings seem to be set to the relevant utf8mb4 setting. Despite that, I am unable to insert the unicode Japanese text.

(By the way, I dont think the 4-byte unicode settings utf8mb4 is necessary here, but it is what I am using because it seemed to fix many other unicode mysql problems)

What other settings in mysql or the system are likely causing this problem? 
What other settings can I/ should I change to allow inserting japanese text appropriately?

EDIT UPDATE: I am on a Japanese computer

Comment: 1) How exactly are you executing that `INSERT` query? On the same command line? 2) How have you ensured that your `INSERT` query really contains UTF-8 encoded text?

Comment: @deceze, (1) it was on the command line from normal windows cmd well, the mysql prompt, which was called via cmd. (2) As mentioned in the answer below, it turned out it was not unicode text from the command line. When I input chcp  into the prompt, it told me it code page 932 (cp932), the windows version of shift-jis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the default system settings, which also affected the input settings at the command line.

Its a Japanese computer, which apparently uses shift-jis encoding using, NOT unicode, by default. The text I was inputting was encoded in this way, and in similar input files I was trying to use.

Therefore, I set the character set to be 'jsis' in the server,
i.e. setting  `character-set-server=sjis` in the my.ini initializer file, and set the mysql character set to be the same by entering `skip-character-set-client-handshake` into the same initilization file.

The character set for the column of course must also be changed via

`ALTER TABLE usert MODIFY username varchar(30) CHARACTER SET sjis COLLATE sjis_japanese_ci`

Now, you can insert the japanese text from command line, and other japanese files which use shift-jis encoding.

Another option for inputting japanese text seems to be cp932, which is the windows version of shift-jis.

Incidentally, if you DO wish to use unicode via command line, apparently powershell has better support for it, rather than the normal cmd I was using, but I haven't tried it personally.

Comment: You do not need to change the column's charset. MySQL just needs to know what encoding its input is (the connection charset). From there it can correctly interpret the text and will convert it on the fly as necessary. You can input SJIS text and store it in a UTF-8 column, MySQL will make that conversion without problem. The other way around (querying data) works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try check character set of Database.

1. Check character set of your Database with command bellow:

```
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

2. If result of 1 different UTF-8 then try command bellow:

```
ALTER DATABASE yourDatabase CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE
utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Hope it work for you.